# Java code help for "retry mysql database connection if fail"

Tags: mysql

I want to reconnect database if fail. How can I do it?

try {

```
       String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:5016";
        dbConmysql = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "root", "root");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: You could use a loop and keep polling it for a connection, after waiting a bit.  But in general if you can't connect to your database the whole application might not run.  Some errors are non recoverable.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **while** if any error is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Just add the query param `autoReconnect=true` to the dbURL.

Instead of:

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:5016";
```

Write:

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:5016?autoReconnect=true";
```

Comment: It tried only for 3 times. Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)